# Array same values clear

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can i clear one value if there is a equal version.
Here my array

```
[1] => Array
              (
              [name] => Peter
              [city] => Texas
)

[2] => Array
              (
              [name] => Hans
              [city] => New York
)

[3] => Array
              (
              [name] => Lex
              [city] => Texas
)
```

So that i only get in my foreach one time Texas

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($array as $newarray) ?>
    <li><?php echo $newarray['city']; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

**Update:**

I try it this way put all cityies in an array. ($array)
With print_r i got this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Vorarlberg
)
Array
(
    [0] => Niederösterreich
)
Array
(
    [0] => Niederösterreich
)
```

After that i try `<?php array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR); ?>`
and with `<?php echo array_unique($regionen, SORT_REGULAR); ?>` i only get three thimes "Array".

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_unique function and you have to   add the SORT_REGULAR flag:

```
$unique_array = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Example :

```
$array  = array(
array("name" => "sundar" , "city" => "madurai"), 
array("name" => "amar" , "city" => "chennai"), 
array("name" => "kumar" , "city" => "madurai"), 
array("name" => "ragu" , "city" => "trichy"), 

);  

foreach ($array as $item) {
    $cityarray[] = $item['city'];
}

 $final_array = array(); 
foreach (array_unique($cityarray) as $key => $city) {

$final_array[] =    $array[$key]; 

}
print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require you to first put all the cities in `$array` and not have it be a multidimensional array?

Comment: Oky i try it but didn't get through it. So i firsts put Citys in an array. 
Than i got this Array ($array)
Array
(
    [0] => Vorarlberg
)
Array
(
    [0] => Niederösterreich
)
Array
(
    [0] => Niederösterreich
)

And i try with <?pho echo array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR); ?>
But only had empty output.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple array as a hash table and `isset` to figure out if you've been through this city before:

```
<?php
    $cities = array();
    foreach ($array as $newArray) {
        if (!isset($cities[$newArray['city']])) {
            $cities[$newArray['city']] = true;

            echo $newArray['city'];
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) together like this:

```
foreach (array_unique(array_column($array, 'city')) as $city) {
    // ...
}
```